# Syncing files from one directory to another in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was using [cpy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpy) with a globbing pattern to find and copy all the files in `src/main/css` and place them in `./dist`.

However now I also have sub directories below `src/main/css` (For example `src/main/css/margins/index.css`) and [cpy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpy) does not include these when copying the files.

Is there an API in Node (fs or path?) that handles this case, or anyone know of a handy package?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using using [copy-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-dir)

```
require('copy-dir').sync(PLI.src.main.css, PLI.DIST);
```

If anyone has a way to do the same thing with the Node and avoiding dependencies please do tell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

var mkdir = function (dir) {
    // making directory without exception if exists
    try {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir, 0755);
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.code != "EEXIST") {
            throw e;
        }
    }
};

var copy = function (src, dest) {
    var readS = fs.createReadStream(src);
    var writeS = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    readS.pipe(writeS);

    readS.on("end", function () {
        // Operation done
    });
};

var copyDir = function (src, dest) {
    mkdir(dest);
    var files = fs.readdirSync(src);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var current = fs.lstatSync(path.join(src, files[i]));
        if (current.isDirectory()) {
            copyDir(path.join(src, files[i]), path.join(dest, files[i]));
        } else if (current.isSymbolicLink()) {
            var symlink = fs.readlinkSync(path.join(src, files[i]));
            fs.symlinkSync(symlink, path.join(dest, files[i]));
        } else {
            copy(path.join(src, files[i]), path.join(dest, files[i]));
        }
    }
};

copyDir('./src', './dest');
```

This piece of code is inspired from https://gist.github.com/tkihira/3014700. I have made some modifications in the original code to get it working as util.pump is obsolete now.